# Pass information from div to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie and I am trying my hand at javascript for the first time. I have a div that calls a javascript. I have a timezone controller, a show.html which renders the timezone.

```
<%= render @user.timezones.paginate(page: params[:page]) %>
```

My partial file for each timzone, _timezone.html,erb :

```
<tr>
<td><%= timezone.name %></td>
<td><%= timezone.city %></td>
<td><%= (timezone.positive ? '+ ' : '- ') + timezone.hours.to_s + ':' + timezone.minutes.to_s %></td>
<td><div class="time-rect-container" data-positive="<%= timezone.positive %>" data-hours="<%= timezone.hours %>" data-minutes="<%= timezone.minutes%>"></div></td>
<td><%= link_to "edit", edit_timezone_path(timezone) %> </td>
<td><%= link_to "delete", timezone, method: :delete,
                                   data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %> </td>
```

This partial will be called for every timezone that I have in my database for each user.

And I have the javascript as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function () {
 time_div = $('.time-rect-container');
 var dt = new Date();

 var x = time_div.data('hours');
 var y = time_div.data('minutes');
 z = time_div.data('positive') 
 utchours = dt.getUTCHours();
 utcminutes = dt.getUTCMinutes();
 utcseconds = dt.getUTCSeconds();
 if (z == true)
    var time = parseInt( utchours + x + (utcminutes + y) / 60) % 24 + ":" + (utcminutes + y) % 60 + ":" + dt.getUTCSeconds();
 time_div.html(time)
}, 1000);
});
```

I want the javascript to return different time each time, depending on the hours, minutes of timezone. However for every timezone, the data I am getting in the javascript is the same, i.e, the hours and minutes from the data I am retrieving remainse same for each timezone. 
Can somebody help fix this?

Comment: tell us what you want to achieve requirement wise. The description in your question is something that here we might not suggest you anything. The first impression of question is what you want to achieve and the way seems not a right way to do it.

Comment: I have a database of different time-zones. I have a render method on the time-zones, that is the _timezone.html.erb I have mentioned. For each time zone, I want to calculate and display the current time in that timezone. So for each timezone, I need to get the data from the database and add/subtract the time-difference and then print it. Is there a way I can send either the timezone difference or the id of each timezone to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Html Data Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_data) for sending info to javascript.

you can generate divs with attribute `data-url` and pass it timezone-id url. Your divs should look like this.

```
<div class="time-rect-container" data-url="/timezones/<%= <timezone id> %>/give_time"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
     time_div = $('.time-rect-container');
     time_div.load(time_div.data('url'));
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I hit a new error, Please look at the updated question.

Comment: better create a new question u mixed things well let me have look. Its not a good way of using stackoverflow u asked a whole new question here and removed previous one